# BASH script get's row data from mySQL and uses that to launch PHP scrips

Tags: mysql, bash

I've been trying for a few hours now to store row data into a BASH var then use that to launch some PHP scripts.

So far, I've only been able to echo out the whole result set. I have since broken that script, so I can't even paste it here. This is what I have, that's not working at all.

```
#! bin/bash
query=`echo "SELECT id FROM searches WHERE running=1 AND id_user=2" | mysql -u root`
```

I've never used BASH before, so I'm completely lost.

What I'm asking for is some resources that can show me how I can connect to mysql, then loop through a result set using the data from that row.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can read `mysql --silent` output into Bash vars with `while read`:

```
>sql="SELECT id FROM searches WHERE running=1 AND id_user=2"
>mysql --silent -u ctrahey test -e "$sql" |while read myid; do
 php -f my_processor.php $myid; 
done
>
```

Notes:

- `sql="...` sets a Bash variable of your sql (not actually necessary, just aides readability)
- `mysql -e` the -e option allows you to pass in a query, so you don't need STDIN
- `mysql --silent` --silent suppresses the extra formatting mysql usually does. in my testing, this was actually also unnecessary (the pipe chars in the output did not mess up Bash)
- `php -f ..` this executes a php file, passing the current id as an arg.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not a good language for interacting with mysql, it only works for very very simple cases. Use php instead (since you mentioned php), it has an api for interacting with mysql databases sanely. And yes, you can [run a php script](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) as you would a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a single command with MySQL, use `mysql -e` or `mysql --execute`. They are the same command, but the second version is more memorable. If you add this flag to the above, the rows will be stored in the variable.

However, as mentioned by geirha, BASH may not be the best language to get row data. But if you choose to parse it wish BASH, `mysql -e` is the right command to execute queries.